# php, how to prevent direct class instantiazation?

Tags: php

lets say I have a very general class:

```
class Money
{
    public __construct($actualCountry)
    {
        $this->actualCountry = $actualCountry;
    }

    public function getValute()
    {
        return according to actual country
    }
}
```

This class needs to be created once, so I have a global factory:

```
final class Factory
{
    private $money;

    public function getMoney()
    {
        if ($this->money == null)
        {
            $this->money = new Money(Config::getCountryCode());
        }
        return $this->money;
    }
}
```

and whenever we want to use:

```
Factory::getMoney()->
```

but today I saw my colleague trying to do:

```
(new Money(Config::getCountryCode()))->getValute();
```

which is obviously wrong, no need multiple occurences. But then how can a class itself say "hey, dont instantize me, use factory"?

I cant set it as singleton, because then everytime:

```
Money::getInstance(Config::getCountryCode());
```

is pointless.

But the real problem is not because it may exists multiple - its the way I always have to pass the current country from config. What is `Config` becames `GlobalConfig`? Thats why the factory to avoid the lot of parameter passing (what if there will be more parameters to `Money`?)

Comment: I think... make the constructor private? Your factory can create it but nothing else can?

Answer (score 5):

I think that you should consider again the Singleton pattern. It fits better in the logic you want.

```
<?php
class Money
{
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct($countryCode)
    {
        #your code here...
    }

    /**
     * Do not include parameter for getInstance.
     * Make the call internally.
     * Now when you have to change Config to GlobalConfig will be painless.
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === self::$instance) {
            return self::$instance = new Money(Config::getCountryCode());
        }

        return  self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 ways to control where an instance is created.

1. Using debug_backtrace you can add control in the constructor of class Money:

   ```
    public __construct($actualCountry)
    {
        $trace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
        foreach($trace as $traceItem) {
            if ($traceItem['class'] == 'Factory') {
                return;
            }
        }   
        throw new Exception('Cannot create class ' . static::class . ' outside of factory');
       }
       $this->actualCountry = $actualCountry;
    }
   ```
2. You can define constructor of class Money as private or protected and use ReflectionClass in Factory:

   ```
    class Money
    {
        private __construct($actualCountry)
        {
            $this->actualCountry = $actualCountry;
        }
    }

    final class Factory
    {
        private $money;

        public function getMoney()
        {
            if ($this->money == null) {
                $reflection = new ReflectionClass('Money');
                $constructor = $reflection->getConstructor();
                $constructor->setAccessible(true);
                $object = $reflection->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
                $constructor->invokeArgs($object, [Config::getCountryCode()]);
                $this->money = $object;
            }
            return $this->money;
    }
   ```

}

Details I described in the article "[Forbidding of creating objects outside factory in PHP](https://medium.com/@marenkov/forbidding-of-creating-objects-outside-factory-in-php-7173d7be6cb4)".

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to completely prevent outside instantiation, because for your Factory to work, the constructor will have to be publically reachable, either directly or indirectly.

You can obscure the constructor by making it private, and adding a static factory method to your class:

```
class Money
{
    private function __construct($actualCountry)
    {
        $this->actualCountry = $actualCountry;
    }

    public static function fromFactory($actualCountry)
    {
        return new static($actualCountry);
    }

    public function getValute()
    {
        // return according to actual country
    }
}

final class Factory
{
    private $money;

    public function getMoney()
    {
        if ($this->money == null)
        {
            $this->money = Money::fromFactory(Config::getCountryCode());
        }
        return $this->money;
    }
}
```

Or you can alter the constructor to require a (typed) second parameter, this being the factory used. However, this won't work if your factory uses static methods, as it does in your example:

```
class Money
{
    public function __construct($actualCountry, Factory $factory)
    {
        $this->actualCountry = $actualCountry;
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        // return according to actual country
    }
}

final class Factory
{
    private $money;

    public function getMoney()
    {
        if ($this->money == null)
        {
            $this->money = new Money(Config::getCountryCode(), $this);
        }
        return $this->money;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I am getting your drift correctly, What you need is [`Abstract Class`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

As you need, an abstract class cannot be initialized directly.

> Classes defined as abstract may not be instantiated,.....

Comment: no, you are wrong, then even the Factory wont be able to create it.

Comment: Factory wont be able to "create it" but it will be able to "extend" it, which is pretty much how it is supposed to be sued. My $0.02 :)